# How to make a C program that finds the numbers in the array and then multiplies it?

Tags: c, arrays

I wanted to make a C program that finds the numbers in the input array and then multiplies it all together, I made the program but it got an issue that I don't know, can anybody help me with it!?

Here is the code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  char t[10];
  int n, z;
  n = 0;

  printf ("please enter a code: \n");
  scanf ("%s", t);
  while (n != '\0')
    {
      if (isdigit (t[n] == 0))
        {
          n++;
        }
      else
        {
          z = t[n];
          z *= z;
        }
    }
  printf ("%d", z);
}
```

Comment: Why did you want to do that just out of the blue? Also, what is the issue? Does it not compile!? What's the error then? Does it compile but crash!? At what point? Do your own work before asking us to do ours.

Comment: The issue that the final result is not right at all, it keeps printing some weird numbers!

Comment: actually am a 16 years old student and am learning C by myself and that code is a part of my sci-fair project!

Comment: @chouaib based on his description and the code he presented, he's not very far off. His code is nothing near polished, but excluding converting ascii to a numberic, it does what he describes (multiplies all of the single digit integers together).  Perhaps before abusing one with statements such as you have, you should spend a little time understanding the situation first.

Comment: @mah and actually user3197769, I am sorry if I was not polite in my previous comment, good luck in learning C.
P.S: mah if you mean the task being done in the code by "situation", well I spent time in understanding it and I did. If you mean other circumstances, I asked the user. All my respect

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated code. There is a comment for each bug that needed correction.
(Note that the comment describes the intention of the corrected code, it doesn't describe the bug.)

```
int temp;

z=1;                          // Initialize z
printf ("please enter a code: \n");
scanf ("%s", n);
while (t[n] != '\0') {        // While there are more characters in the string 
  if (isdigit (t[n])) {       // Check if the character is a digit
      temp = t[n] - '0';      // Convert character digit to corresponding number.
      z *= temp;
  }
  n++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you don't actually use `t` in your `while` loop. Your `while` loop only uses `n` which is set to `0` and never modified.

Your second problem is that you may be better off to use `scanf("%d", &number);` to scan numbers straight away.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the help!
Second, am in need to input a character not a number directly, and that's the point it's to find the number within the array!

Comment: It might be worth adding that by using scanf("%s", t); you are getting the string representation of a number, not an actual number. So, if you type '123', when you do t[n] (lets assume n = 0) you are actually getting the character '1', which would have a value of 49. That's why it's probably better to use the above to input numbers. If you do want to use a string input for whatever reason, then remember to subtract 48 from the character ('1' == 49, 49 - 48 = 1. Again, '2' == 50, 50 - 48 = 2) so that you have the correct integer you want to multiply.

Comment: Yeah I got it!
Thank you so much!

Comment: @SergeyL you point out two problems however neither of them is valid (at least not a valid explanation). `n` _is_ modified in the loop, and while he might be "better off" with scanning in a number when he needs a number, that's not what he needs in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`z` should be initialized to `1`. and remove "`z = t[n];`"

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   char a[5] ;
   int b=1, n=0,m=0;
   scanf("%s",a);

   while (n <5 )
   {
       if (!isdigit(a[n])) 
       {
           n++;
           m++;
       }
       else{
           b *= (a[n]-'0');
           n++;
       }
   }

   if(m==5) b=0;
   printf("%d\n",b);

}
```